# Whera can I found old documentation for JPA 1.0

Tags: documentation, legacy

A legacy project is using JPA 1.0 and I would like to read the documentation. However I fail to access Spring Data JPA documentation beyond 1.8.

Is there an archive of old documentation available somewhere?

-Petri Sirkkala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link would be helpful which contains a pdf.

http://jpaobjects.sourceforge.net/m2-site/main/documentation/docbkx/pdf/user-guide.pdf

Comment: I hope this helps.